# Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function

Tags: mongodb, express

i want to send the updatedUser informations plus an image file in the response but I get this kind of error: " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:69044) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.".i googled this error but nothing helpful, so this is my code :

```
userRouter.post("/upload/:id",async(req, res)=> {
    const user_id = req.params.id;
   const pp = req.files.productImage;
   const {data} = pp;  
   const namePp =  uuidv4() + '.' + pp.name.split('.').pop();
   pp.mv("./picturesProfile/" + namePp);
  
   const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, {new: true},{image: namePp},   function (err, docs) {
   
   if(err) {
console.log(err)
   } else {
return docs
   }
})
console.log(updatedUser)
res.send({updatedUser,pp});

 

})
```

Comment: This error message doesn't say a lot, as it's just saying that some promise was rejected. You may either - try/catch the whole code in this route and console.log the error, or alternatively you may use [process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => console.log(error))](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection) to catch any promise error

Comment: i'm trying to use try{}catch around updatedUser but it return the same error

Comment: It doesn't have to be in `updatedUser` declaration - the whole route function here is `async`, therefore even if `pp.mv` will throw an error it will end up as rejected promise (of the whole route). Because of that, you may either wrap all, or use the global `unhandledRejection` event on `process`.

Async functions under the hood are using `Promise`s, so even synchronous error will result in rejected promise

Comment: it send me this error: " MongooseError: Query was already executed: User.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("62b572dd314038da02f68b05")..."

Comment: i guess the problem is on the updatedUser.how to handle his result

Comment: One problem I definitely see here is invalid arguments ordering - `options` and `updates` arguments are mismatched: it should be `user_id, {image: namePp}, {new: true}` instead. Could you try that?

Comment: now the error has change  "MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]"

Comment: Another problem may be that I don't think that the Mongoose will return promise - most likely the line would need to be:

```
const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, { image: namePp }, { new: true }).exec()
```

Comment: it remain the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245974/discussion-between-dawid-rusnak-and-borhen-kalboussi).

Answer (score 0):

This one will work you!

```
const doc = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id,
{ $set: { "image": namePp }},
{
new: true,
runValidators : true
});
```

Comment: `$set` is not necessary though, as when you pass an object of values, it will assume `$set` anyway :) Beside, there is a typo - should be `user_id` instead of `user._id`. On the other side, good advice with `runValidators` - it's worth using it here.